# JQuery Flot - Grid lines not showing through filled lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flot

I'm trying to create one real-time flot and ***my problem is that I can't get to see the flot grid through the filling of my data's lines***..

***If you have any idea to get my filling a bit transparent*** like the picture below, I'd like to apply it as well on my Fiddle!

---

What I'm trying to achieve is something like that:
[Picture of what I try to get](http://syrach.free.fr/downloads/exempleFlot.jpg)

Here is the Fiddle on what I'm working: 
[My flot on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FSw9H/100/)

Code:

---

```
$(function () {

    getRandomData = function(){
        var rV = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
             rV.push([i,Math.random() * 10]);
        }
        return rV;
    }

    getRandomDataa = function(){
        var rV = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
             rV.push([i,Math.random() * 10 + 5]);
        }
        return rV;
    }

    getSeriesObj = function() {
        return [
        {
            data: getRandomDataa(),
            lines: { 
                show: true, 
                fill: true,
                lineWidth: 5,
                fillColor: { colors: [ "#b38618", "#b38618" ] },
                tickColor: "#FFFFFF",
                tickLength: 5
            }
        }, {
            data: getRandomData(),
            lines: {
                show: true,
                lineWidth: 0,
                fill: true,
                fillColor: { colors: [ "#1A508B", "#1A508B" ] },
                tickColor: "#FFFFFF",
                tickLength: 5
            }
        }];
    }

    update = function(){
        plot.setData(getSeriesObj());
        plot.draw();
        setTimeout(update, 1000);
    }

    var flotOptions = {  
        series: {
            shadowSize: 0,  // Drawing is faster without shadows
            tickColor: "#FFFFFF"
        },
        yaxis: {
            min: 0, 
            autoscaleMargin: 0,
            position: "right",
            transform: function (v) { return -v; },     /* Invert data on Y axis */
            inverseTransform: function (v) { return -v; }, 
            font: { color: "#FFFFFF" },
            tickColor: "#FFFFFF"
        },
        grid: {
            backgroundColor: { colors: [ "#EDC240", "#EDC240" ], opacity: 0.5 }, // "Ground" color (May be a color gradient)
            show: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
            verticalLines: true,
            horizontalLines: true,
            tickColor: "#FFFFFF"
        }
    }; 

    var plot = $.plot("#placeholder", getSeriesObj(), flotOptions);

    setTimeout(update, 1000);
});
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`rgba()`](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css3_colors.asp) color specification with flot to [specify the fill color](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-data-series) and alpha level (transparency):

```
fillColor: { colors: [ "rgba(179, 134, 24, .2)", "rgba(179, 134, 24, .2)" ] },
```

An alpha value of `0` is fully transparent, while an alpha value of `1` is fully opaque.